# Perl Model class for both ORM and web forms

Tags: perl, model-view-controller, model, formbuilder, database-abstraction

Is there a perl module or a framework which will let me define my data model for both database and web forms in one place?

Something like a fusion of Class::DBI with CGI::Formbuilder?

So that I'll be able to define my data classes, their relationships, fields and validation rules in one place and it will "magically" create/alter database schema for me, generate forms on the fly and validate user input.

I'm considering to use Dancer or Mojolicious as a web framework, but still struggling on which model classes to choose.

Many thanks.

Comment: http://p3rl.org/HTML::FormHandler::TraitFor::Model::DBIC